# convert multipart/form-data to dict python

Tags: python, aws-api-gateway

I need get the data of a body from `multipart/form-data` pasted for api gateway to python this is the data on the body:

```
b'----------------------------489480454721201967418418\\r\\nContent-
Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\\r\\n\\r\\n\"12345rete\"\\r\\n
----------------------------489480454721201967418418--\\r\\n'
```

My code is:

```
data = base64.b64decode(event["body"])
    c_type, c_data = parse_header(event["params"]['header']['Content-Type'])
    assert c_type == 'multipart/form-data'
    c_data["boundary"] = bytes(c_data["boundary"], "utf-8")
    c_data["CONTENT-LENGTH"] = 10
    form_data = parse_multipart(BytesIO(data), c_data)
    print(form_data["name"])
```

this is the result

`````
"name": [
            ""
        ]
````
`````

Comment: Use `.decode()` to turn it into a string and use any number of string processing methods to get your data (regex, a header parser, etc.)

Comment: @Grismar i use cgi but not map the data

Comment: I'm sorry, but your example does not work by itself and it's unclear what exactly your problem is, other than that name apparently comes out as `""` instead of `"name"` - please complete your example so that it can be run and verified by people looking at your post, so they can suggest concrete improvements. Currently it's unclear what `event` is and how you obtain it (I'm guessing the imports are from `cgi` and `io`)